# Force webpage under Internet Explorer to be executed in Intranet browser mode

Tags: internet-explorer, wamp, intranet

Debugging a website not working under IE ([my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332530/difference-between-local-execution-wamp-and-online-website), [the post for the very specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331452/webpage-with-mootools-formcheck-not-working-correctly-on-ie-but-working-perfectly)) (but working under Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and SeaMonkey) I've noticed that my website works perfectly with IE on Wamp (intranet mode).

I've already put my settings regarding options for Internet websites like the ones for the Intranet with no result.

My guess is that there must be more general settings. So I'd like to force the execution of my website in intranet mode.

EDIT: I know that this question might not seem relevant for Stack Overflow but it's tightly related to the execution of MooTools code in my page hence its place here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force IE to view your website as an intranet site by adding your site's fqdn to the Intranet Zone in Internet Options.

1. Open IE Internet Options
2. Click the Security Tab
3. Click the Intranet Zone
4. Click Sites
5. Click Advanced
6. Add your web site's fully qualified domain name.
7. Done

You can verify IE is treating your site as an intranet site by navigating to you site and verifying their is an intranet icon on the bottom right corner of the IE status bar.  May vary depending upon IE version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (which unfortunately doesn't solve my problem :-) )